# C# Как обновлять игру через лаунчер по отдельным файлам?

Tags: c#, wpf, launcher

Я делаю лаунчер для игры на C# WPF. Смотря на обновление игр в Steam, лаунчер Crossout, World of Tanks, Samp и прочие лаунчеры таких больших игр. Я видел, что там обновление происходит не устанавливая каждый раз игру заново, а если удалил какой-то файл, то лаунчер это поймёт и восстановит.

Игра залита в репозиторий GitHub. Я не понял, как делать нечто вроде клонирования и в итоге получил ссылку на скачивание всего репозитория как архив и из кода разархивирую.

Встала проблема с обновлением. Я могу сделать отдельный репозиторий для патчей и туда просто закидывать изменённые файлы, а дальше распаковывать в игру, но мне кажется это провальным. Если я удалю файл, то без понятия как сделать так, чтобы это понял лаунчер.

Подскажите способы реализовать то что нужно, либо куда копать.

Comment: Предположу, что лаунчер знает контрольную сумму файла и список файлов на сервере и на клиенте. Если они разные - обновляет файл. 
также он во время работы следит за состоянием каталогов и подписан на обновления с сервера.

Comment: Берете все файлы, делаете их "снимок" (сохраняя размер, md5 (или аналог), путь), сохраняете в файлик, далее уже на основе этих данных проверяете клиент игры, если файла нет, файл имеет другой размер, или у файла другой md5, то значит с этим файлом что-то не так, а значит надо его восстановить. Как? А зависит от вас, обычно есть сервер с файлами, от куда качается все, последнее время в моде p2p (торрент), где сервером является каждый игрок. Патчи по аналогии, ищите разницу между старой версией и новой, эту разницу и отправляете игрокам. Вот и вся логика.

Comment: Если git, то обновление командой `git pull` делается. Почитайте документацию по git, но выбор гита в качестве источника обновления - странный.